# Search button error: Trying to get property 'showname' of non-object (View

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, frameworks

I get this error:
Trying to get property 'showname' of non-object (View: /home/laravel/web/laravel.swt101.eu/public_html/abonamenty/resources/views/proforms/index.blade.php)
on this line

```
<td>{{ $proform->user->showname }}</td>
```

After clicking search button in my view.
Search button in code is at the begining of my view :

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Zarządzanie proformami</h2>
            </div>


 <div class="col-md-4">
<form action="/search3" method="get">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="search" name="search" class="form-control">
<span class="input-group-prepend">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Wyszukaj</button>
</span>
</div>
</form>
</div>           

            <div class="pull-right">
                @can('product-create')
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('proforms.create') }}"> Utwórz nową proformę</a>
                @endcan
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <p>{{ $message }}</p>
        </div>
    @endif


    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>

            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('id', 'Numer')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('proformnumber', 'Numer proformy')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('user_id', 'Kontrachent')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('proformdate', 'Data wystawienia')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('selldate', 'Data sprzedaży')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('paymentdate', 'Termin płatności')</th> 
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('status', 'Status')</th> 
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('nettotal', 'Netto razem')</th>
            <th scope="col">@sortablelink('grosstotal', 'Brutto razem')</th>              
            <th width="280px">Akcja</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($proforms as $proform)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $proform->proformnumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ $proform->user->showname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $proform->proformdate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $proform->selldate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $proform->paymentdate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $proform->status }}</td>
            <td>{{ $proform->nettotal }}</td>
            <td>{{ $proform->grosstotal }}</td>

            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('proforms.destroy',$proform->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('proforms.show',$proform->id) }}">Więcej</a>
                    @can('product-edit')
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('proforms.edit',$proform->id) }}">Edytu</a>
                    @endcan


                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    @can('product-delete')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Usuń</button>
                    @endcan
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

{!! $proforms ?? ''->appends(request()->except('page'))->render() !!}
 


<p class="text-center text-primary"><small>ARTplus 2020</small></p>
@endsection
```

This is my routes:

```
Auth::routes();
   
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
   
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
Route::resource('roles', 'RoleController');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
Route::resource('permissions', 'PermissionController');
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
Route::resource('invoices', 'InvoiceController');

Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
Route::resource('invoices', 'InvoiceController');
Route::resource('proforms', 'ProformController');
Route::get('/search', 'UserController@search');
Route::get('/search2', 'ProductController@search2');
Route::get('/search3', 'ProformController@search3');
Route::get('data', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('posts', 'PostController@index');
Route::get('/prodview', 'TestController@prodfunct');
```

This is search function in my controller:

```
public function search3(Request $request)
{
$search = $request->get('search');
$requestData = ['showname'];
    
$query = User::query();
foreach ($requestData as $field){
$query->orWhere($field, 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
}
$data2=$query->paginate(5);
return view('proforms.index', ['proforms' => $data2])->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

This is my user model:

```
<?php
  
namespace App;
  
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

  
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use HasRoles;
    use Sortable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'surname', 'showname', 'business', 'NIP', 'PESEL', 'address', 'city', 'postalcode', 'phone', 'comments', 
    ];
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
  
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
    public $sortable = ['name',
                        'email',
                         'surname', 
                        'showname', 
                        'business',
                        'address',
                        'city',
                        'phone',
                        'role',
                       ];
    
        public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
        public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Invoice');
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions about this error are asked a few times a day on Stackoverflow... `$proform->user` is `null`, so `$proform->user->showname` cannot be chained, as `null->showname` is invalid. Add some code to ensure `user` is loaded, or check that `user` is not `null` before trying to call `->showname`.

Comment: But i am getting tihs error after searching word in column showname in table users. This value isn't null.

Comment: You're looping over `$proforms`, meaning that on one of your loops, `$proform->user` is `null`. When you search, `$proforms` likely changes, but regardless, **yes, your value is `null`**

Comment: But it's not true. I have to choose user for add proform. Every proform has got user with showname.

Comment: Your error clearly states otherwise... If you do `{{ $proform->user->showname ?? 'N/A' }}` does the error go away? Or, while looping, `@if(!$proform->user) {{ dd($proform) }} @endif`; that'll show you which `$proform` doesn't have a `user`.

Comment: Error go away after {{ $proform->user->showname ?? 'N/A' }} but searching not working , because is showing empty table when i am searching word witch is in table

Comment: Then there's another issue with your searching logic... I'm not sure what that would be though; you'll need to do some more debugging. Either way, the immediate issue you specified (property of non-object) has been solved (and could have been if you had just followed the instructions in my first comment instead of arguing the point... *"check that `user` is not `null` before trying to call `->showname`"*)